How to squash every merge commit on a branch (like `git rebase --squash-merges` instead of `--rebase-merges`)?
I'm trying to reconcile a very large feature branch with hundreds of commits that multiple teams and agencies worked on for a long time period. Unfortunately due to corporate policy issues it wasn't possible to enforce a consistent merging strategy across the teams, so now the branch is inconsistent, containing mostly squashed merges plus dozens of merge commits that create a messy commit history and conflicts on a simple  git rebase -i whenever individual commits within a merge conflict with temporally-adjacent commits from other merges that were worked on in parallel at a similar point in time.
I could manually squash all the commits and merge commits with something like git rebase -i --rebase-merges, but that introduces a risk of human error as I need to manually re-order dozens of commits and merge-commits, and it'd be easy to accidentally squash a commit into the wrong merge-commit or in the wrong order.
Git already knows which commits belong to which merge commits, so it should be possible to remove the risk of human error by automating this. I hoped there would be something like git rebase --squash-merges that does an autosquash on every commit into its merge commit as if that merge had been a squash-merge, but this feature doesn't appear to exist (but it might be possible to write a chain of commands that works this way using commands that list the commits of each merge commit?).
Is there some way I can get Git to go through the commits in a branch and automatically squash loose commits into their merge-commits in the right order, without risking human error by doing it manually?

Here's an example editted extract from around line 300 of the output of git rebase -i --rebase-merges some-branch. Here we have two merges with one commit each and two squash-merges. Due to the time gap between the commits and their merges, regular rebases see merge conflicts between "make widget" and "Create McGuffin". :
pick af697c57 Release: 1.2.1
label branch-point-9
pick 3e50d3ae XYZ-32: Create McGuffin (#394)
label merge

# Branch org-XYZ-29-make-widget
reset branch-point-9 # Release: 1.2.1
pick 4d53b13c feat: make widget for XYZ-29
merge -C 0d9d6676 merge # merge
label org-XYZ-29-make-widget

# Branch merge-2
reset merge # XYZ-32: Create McGuffin (#394)
merge -C 04d11323 org-XYZ-29-make-widget # Merge pull request #400 from org/XYZ-29/make-widget
pick 060bbde5 XYZ-27: splice mainbrace (#399)
pick 50ae56cf XYZ-36: reticulate splines (#397)
label merge-2

I want to squash this (and every such case) down into something like this (which should have no conflicts because any conflicts were already resolved in the merges), using what Git already knows about which commits belong to to which merge commits and how the merges were reconciled:
pick af697c57 Release: 1.2.1
pick XXXXXXXX XYZ-32: Create McGuffin (#394) # commit squashed into its merge commit
pick YYYYYYYY Merge pull request #400 from org/XYZ-29/make-widget # commit squashed into its merge commit
pick 060bbde5 XYZ-27: splice mainbrace (#399)
pick 50ae56cf XYZ-36: reticulate splines (#397)

...which I think could be achieved manually in an interactive rebase by carefully re-ordering commits under their merge commits, squashing into those, and then picked the squashed merge as a regular commit? But doing this at scale adds a risk of human error.

If I get it correctly, what you would like to do a single line of commits that would go over the list of first parents of a given branch and removing all the possible 2nd (and more) parents from each of those commits.... so you get a straight line, no merges... is that right? And of course, each new commit would have to match 1:1 the metadata of the original commit (author, comment, files and content). does that match what you would like to see?

It's unclear what the problem is. Show an example commit graph, what you want to do with it, and how the result should look like.

"each new commit would have to match 1:1 the metadata of the original commit" - yes in so far as it would if squash (or fixup) was used in an interactive rebase. I want to squash the individual commits of each merge commit into one regular commit per merge, with each squashed commit joining the single line of commits at the position where the merge commit was.

Git stores snapshots and records one or more parents for each commit. Regular commits have a single parent and merge commits have two parents (or more). With that knowledge it should become clear that you want to rewrite the commits to only contain a single parent so that history becomes linear. Each merge commit's snapshot already points to the merge result.
The usual advice applies: do not rewrite published/shared history (and keep backups).
filter-branch --parent-filter can do exactly that:

This is the filter for rewriting the commit’s parent list. It will receive the parent string on stdin and shall output the new parent string on stdout. The parent string is in the format described in git-commit-tree: empty for the initial commit, "-p parent" for a normal commit and "-p parent1 -p parent2 -p parent3 …​" for a merge commit.

Thus, to only keep -p parent1 and drop all other parents:
git filter-branch --parent-filter 'cut -d" " -f1,2' -- main..yourbranch

This will turn history such as:
F     < yourbranch
|\
D E
| |\
|/ /
B C
|/
A     < main

into this (removing all but the first parent from the parent list):
F'    < yourbranch
|
D E'
| |
|/ 
B C
|/
A     < main

(' (prime) marks the "changed commits" – those that will end up with a different hash. They are actually new commit objects)
Note that you will end up with unreachable commits, but you can simply abandon them. The reachable history is only this:
F'    < yourbranch
|
D
|
B
|
A     < main

In a follow-up step, you might want to reword the rewritten merge commits with an interactive rebase to contain a sensible commit message.

cut -d" " -f1,2? delimiter and fields!

Haha, yes. Brainfart. Thanks!

This looks like it does what I want, but I'm going to carefully read the "SAFETY" section of https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch before proceeding, given the warnings and that git no longer recommends using filter-branch! Reading the docs it sounds like it re-writes the history files of the original commits (rather than creating new altered copies with new hashes), so could have side effects on other branches that contain the same commits, is that right or did I misunderstand?

@user56reinstatemonica8 you misunderstood. You cannot change existing commits. You can only create new commits (with different hashes). Commits with the same hash are the same commit. filter-branch is local, you can run it, inspect the result and then only publish the single rewritten branch.

This seems to work, but somehow there were stray spaces in my commit parent strings causing errors like "error: switch `p' requires a value". Piping the parent strings through xargs first seemed to fix that, like --parent-filter 'xargs | cut -d" " -f1,2'

@user56reinstatemonica8 interesting (and good to know). I wouldn't have expected spaces to show up. Another way around would probably be --parent-filter "awk '{print \$1,\$2}'" or --parent-filter 'tr -s " " " " | cut -d" " -f1,2'

Please just use git-filter-repo(1) instead.

@Guildenstern feel free to provide another answer which solves this problem with filter-repo. (I assume --commit-callback with something like commit.parents = commit.parents[:1]?)

@Guildenstern Please be warned that git filter-repo --commit-callback is buggy. May be it's only bug in commit.skip() but I would be very afraid to use it without extensive testing.

@knittl can the same recipe be provided but using git filter-repo instead?

@eftshift0 yes, feel free to provide another answer that uses git filter-repo. I don't have the 3rd-party filter-repo installed and have never used it productively, thus cannot provide a tested answer myself. filter-branch is simple enough and works perfectly for tasks such as the one requested by OP.

Might take it up for self-learning's sake :-D
